# piping of perl and C scripts

Tags: c, perl, state-machine

i want to create a simple state machine using C but all the events in the respective states are executed using perl scripts.so is there any way to link these perl and C scripts so that when i go to a particular state in a state machine it should execute the particular function(event) defined in the perl script..how to proceed?      or 
writing the state machine using perl is better than this?

Comment: What benefits are you expecting of writing the state-machine part in C? Without that information, your question is impossible to answer. (And keeping it all in one language, one the face of it, is usually better.)

Comment: I agree with @Mat, but if you have to then there are usually many alternative functions you can use to call external programs, and they all depend on your platform (Windows, Linux).

Comment: By all means, write your state machine in Perl. If that is not an option, read perl's "perlembed" manual page and embed a copy of perl in your C program. But really. Write it in Perl unless that's too slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your aim is to improve the speed of an existing module by extracting out some of the heavy lifting to C functions, then try using the Perl XS interface to write (some of) a module in C.

See http://perldoc.perl.org/perlxs.html for more information.